# onMouseOver() function does not trigger in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks

So I am trying to use onMouseOver on my React component like this

```
<CookieDetails
  key={cookie.id}
  name={cookie.name}
  cost={cookie.cost}
  value={cookie.cost}
  numOwned={purchasedItems[cookie.id]}
  onMouseOver={event => {
    console.log('cookies');
    if (numCookies < cookie.cost) {
      alert('Not Enough Cookies');
      return;
    }
    setPurchasedItems({
      ...purchasedItems,
      [cookie.id]: purchasedItems[cookie.id] + 1,
    });
    setNumCookies(numCookies - cookie.cost);
    console.log('purchased', purchasedItems[cookie.id], numCookies);
  }}
/>;
```

and here is whats inside my component for now

```
import React from 'react';
const CookieDetails = ({ name, cost, value, numOwned }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="cookie-details-wrapper">
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <p>Cost:{cost}</p>
        <p>Value:{value}</p>
        <p>Owned:{numOwned}</p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CookieDetails;
```

However when I mouse over my component, nothing happens. Doesn't event console log cookies. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `onMouseOver` is just a prop to `CookieDetails`. You have to actually pass it to an element that will call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CookieDetails` isn't a DOM element (so it doesn't have native handling for events) it is a component you wrote. You don't do anything with the `onMouseOver` prop.

You need to read that prop and attach it to a DOM element (like the `div`).

```
const CookieDetails = ({ name, cost, value, numOwned, onMouseOver }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div onMouseOver={onMouseOver} className="cookie-details-wrapper">
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thanks for the concise but detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

So here `onMouseOver` is a prop that you are passing to children. You need to trigger `onMouseOver` on children

```
<CookieDetails
  key={cookie.id}
  name={cookie.name}
  cost={cookie.cost}
  value={cookie.cost}
  numOwned={purchasedItems[cookie.id]}
  onMouseOver={event => {
    console.log('cookies');
    if (numCookies < cookie.cost) {
      alert('Not Enough Cookies');
      return;
    }
    setPurchasedItems({
      ...purchasedItems,
      [cookie.id]: purchasedItems[cookie.id] + 1,
    });
    setNumCookies(numCookies - cookie.cost);
    console.log('purchased', purchasedItems[cookie.id], numCookies);
  }}
/>;



import React from 'react';
const CookieDetails = ({ name, cost, value, numOwned, onMouseOver }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="cookie-details-wrapper" onMouseOver={onMouseOver}>
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <p>Cost:{cost}</p>
        <p>Value:{value}</p>
        <p>Owned:{numOwned}</p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CookieDetails;
```